# QStyleOptionViewItem argument in paint function - what to do with it?

Tags: c++, qt

in paint function:

```
void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex &index) const
```

the option argument is const so it cannot/shouldn't be changed, for what purpose is this argument there and how one can use it?

Answer (score 1):

> The `QStyleOptionViewItem` class is used to describe the parameters
>   used to draw an item in a view widget.

You need this in order to get the `rect` where your paint function will draw.

Also based on its state you can change the way the delegate will be drawn. For example :

```
if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
   painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());

painter->drawText(option.rect, aStringToDraw);
```